# How to find a (set of) mapping between two polygons?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, linear-transformations

Provided that there are two set of points in a plane, we can find two minimum convex polygons containing these points. Two polygons may have the same or different amount of vertices, we assume polygon A has N vertices and polygon B has M vertices, how can we find a set of mappings M that containing all feasible mapping m(i) satisfying m(i)*A ∈ B, where A is a 2*N matrix and B is 2*M and m(i) is 2*2 mapping matrix?

If m(i) is diagonal matrix then we can find a intersection of all mappings map every vertex of A inside B, but if m(i) is full-element matrix, how to find a solution?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be explicit enough, but here's one approach (also, it appears that you're assuming that the point sets are finite):

1) A convex shape can be described by the intersection of a collection of hyperspaces.  In other words, a collection of $\{(x,y):ax+by\leq c\}$.

2) Write $M=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}$.

3) For each point $(r,s)$ in the first set, prove that $M(r,s)$ satisfies all the inequalities of the convex hull of the second set.

4) Since the vertices of the convex hull of the first set are all points of the first set, step 3 can be reduced to the case where $(r,s)$ is a vertex of the convex hull.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In step 3, you said find $M(r,s)$ satisfies all the inequalities of the convex hull of the second set, can I interpret it as that for every $M(r,s)$ satisfies all the inequalities, $a_{11}$, $a_{12}$, $a_{21}$ and $a_{22}$ construct a hyper-halfspace? So for every $(r,s)$ which is the vertex of the first set, there is a corresponding hyper-halfspace, if we find the intersection of thses hyper-halfspace, then we find the set of all $M$?

Comment: That sounds right.  For every corner of the convex hull of the first set, the image of that point must satisfy every inequality.  The matrices that satisfy all of these conditions describe the appropriate matrices.

Comment: But how to find matrices, even one matrix, that satisfy all of these conditions seems to be difficult. Have you got any idea?